# Recorrer array multidimensional php

Tags: php, array

Intento recorrer y obtener los datos de este array  multidimensional que a su ves lo obtengo de un .json  :

```
$resjson = '{"response":{"count":377,"items":[{"id":217775120,"first_name":"Hernán","last_name":"Báez","online":0},{"id":195876267,"first_name":"Padisc","last_name":"Vintage","online":0},{"id":300583272,"first_name":"Emiliano","last_name":"Grecco","online":0},{"id":188512977,"first_name":"Espanol","last_name":"Network","online":0},{"id":286516269,"first_name":"Dani","last_name":"Dan","online":0},{"id":526309153,"first_name":"Leonardo","last_name":"Sánchez","online":0},{"id":264060759,"first_name":"Miguel","last_name":"Zavarof","online":0},{"id":318847339,"first_name":"Canalpelis","last_name":"Online","online":0},{"id":282800022,"first_name":"Josemaria","last_name":"Nieto Tierra","online":0},{"id":173457305,"first_name":"Teodoro","last_name":"Lopez","online":0},{"id":520902659,"first_name":"Blue","last_name":"Love","online":0},{"id":162523459,"first_name":"Marcos","last_name":"Férnandez","online":0},{"id":502843767,"first_name":"Guillermo","last_name":"Calderon","online":0},{"id":494597552,"first_name":"Carina-Eugenia","last_name":"Calonga","online":0},{"id":336520601,"first_name":"Román","last_name":"Ruiz","online":0},{"id":357708754,"first_name":"Ciudad","last_name":"Cultural","online":0},{"id":421137904,"first_name":"Rafa","last_name":"Castro","online":0},{"id":353603786,"first_name":"Ed","last_name":"Vallejo","online":0},{"id":262003746,"first_name":"Alejandro","last_name":"Frutos-Comparetto","online":0},{"id":538493295,"first_name":"Raúl","last_name":"Caraveo Toledo","online":0},{"id":400782191,"first_name":"Xwall","last_name":"Ricardi","online":0},{"id":210222972,"first_name":"Gen","last_name":"Iero","online":0},{"id":325434135,"first_name":"Iván","last_name":"Villar","online":0},{"id":311177154,"first_name":"Francisco-Javier","last_name":"Calzada-Lopez","online":0},{"id":169051516,"first_name":"Pepe","last_name":"Tansolo","online":0},{"id":312662742,"first_name":"Anabel","last_name":"Rodriguez","online":0},{"id":331548225,"first_name":"Jose","last_name":"Gomez","online":0},{"id":349933730,"first_name":"Viktor","last_name":"Grigorievich","online":0},{"id":288056567,"first_name":"Franco","last_name":"Liotta","online":0},{"id":420661927,"first_name":"William","last_name":"Clinton","online":0},{"id":164133743,"first_name":"Peliculaskid","last_name":"Com","online":0},{"id":335518207,"first_name":"César","last_name":"Eduardo","online":0},{"id":205049120,"first_name":"Carlos","last_name":"Salgado","online":0},{"id":432792923,"first_name":"Emilio","last_name":"Gomez-Vera","online":0},{"id":199299884,"first_name":"Aleister","last_name":"Crowley","online":0},{"id":143625934,"first_name":"Enrique","last_name":"Amaya","online":0},{"id":365862403,"first_name":"Nestor","last_name":"Castro","online":0},{"id":220163416,"first_name":"Mia","last_name":"Solorzano","online":0},{"id":285677321,"first_name":"Luna","last_name":"Gelida","online":0},{"id":336166138,"first_name":"Ana","last_name":"Rang","online":0},{"id":366348914,"first_name":"Agenda","last_name":"Sociocultural","online":0},{"id":144629714,"first_name":"Tonalli","last_name":"Arteaga","online":0},{"id":526854716,"first_name":"Miguel","last_name":"Martínez","online":0},{"id":274247897,"first_name":"Jorge","last_name":"Carmona","online":0},{"id":494721586,"first_name":"Johnbritto","last_name":"Britto","online":0},{"id":524461342,"first_name":"Richard","last_name":"Mazzoccone","online":0},{"id":465222660,"first_name":"Mauro","last_name":"Buitrago","online":0},{"id":231767284,"first_name":"Silvia","last_name":"Caadas","online":0},{"id":215306065,"first_name":"Darío","last_name":"Billani","online":0},{"id":172382488,"first_name":"Chimo","last_name":"Dimension","online":0},{"id":253572519,"first_name":"Carmen","last_name":"Oliveros","online":0},{"id":57067305,"first_name":"David","last_name":"Bofill","online":0},{"id":529416825,"first_name":"Sibila","last_name":"Crombas","online":0},{"id":273480697,"first_name":"Sandra","last_name":"Martinez Mancebo","online":0},{"id":184056171,"first_name":"Estefania","last_name":"Farias","online":0}]}}';

$array = json_decode($resjson,true); 

  $array=  Array (
    [response] => Array ( 
    [count] => 376 [items] => Array (
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 300583272 [first_name] => Emiliano [last_name] => Grecco [online] => 0 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 195876267 [first_name] => Padisc [last_name] => Vintage [online] => 0 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 217775120 [first_name] => Hernán [last_name] => Báez [online] => 0 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 188512977 [first_name] => Espanol [last_name] => Network [online] => 0 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 286516269 [first_name] => Dani [last_name] => Dan [online] => 0 )
    [5] => Array ( [id] => 526309153 [first_name] => Leonardo [last_name] => Sánchez [online] => 0 )
    [6] => Array ( [id] => 264060759 [first_name] => Miguel [last_name] => Zavarof [online] => 0 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [id] => 282800022 [first_name] => Josemaria [last_name] => Nieto Tierra [online] => 0 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [id] => 318847339 [first_name] => Canalpelis [last_name] => Online [online] => 0 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [id] => 173457305 [first_name] => Teodoro [last_name] => Lopez [online] => 0 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [id] => 520902659 [first_name] => Blue [last_name] => Love [online] => 1 [online_app] => 2274003 [online_mobile] => 1 ) 
    [11] => Array ( [id] => 162523459 [first_name] => Marcos [last_name] => Férnandez [online] => 0 ) 
    [12] => Array ( [id] => 502843767 [first_name] => Guillermo [last_name] => Calderon [online] => 0 ) 
    [13] => Array ( [id] => 494597552 [first_name] => Carina-Eugenia [last_name] => Calonga [online] => 0 ) 
    [14] => Array ( [id] => 336520601 [first_name] => Román [last_name] => Ruiz [online] => 0 ) 
    [15] => Array ( [id] => 357708754 [first_name] => Ciudad [last_name] => Cultural [online] => 0 ) 
    [16] => Array ( [id] => 421137904 [first_name] => Rafa [last_name] => Castro [online] => 0 ) 
    [17] => Array ( [id] => 353603786 [first_name] => Ed [last_name] => Vallejo [online] => 0 ) 
    [18] => Array ( [id] => 262003746 [first_name] => Alejandro [last_name] => Frutos-Comparetto [online] => 0 ) 
    [19] => Array ( [id] => 538493295 [first_name] => Raúl [last_name] => Caraveo Toledo [online] => 0 ) 
    [20] => Array ( [id] => 400782191 [first_name] => Xwall [last_name] => Ricardi [online] => 0 ) 
    [21] => Array ( [id] => 325434135 [first_name] => Iván [last_name] => Villar [online] => 0 ) 
    [22] => Array ( [id] => 210222972 [first_name] => Gen [last_name] => Iero [online] => 0 ) 
    [23] => Array ( [id] => 311177154 [first_name] => Francisco-Javier [last_name] => Calzada-Lopez [online] => 0 ) 
    [24] => Array ( [id] => 169051516 [first_name] => Pepe [last_name] => Tansolo [online] => 0 ) 
    [25] => Array ( [id] => 331548225 [first_name] => Jose [last_name] => Gomez [online] => 0 ) 
    [26] => Array ( [id] => 288056567 [first_name] => Franco [last_name] => Liotta [online] => 0 ) 
    [27] => Array ( [id] => 312662742 [first_name] => Anabel [last_name] => Rodriguez [online] => 0 ) 
    [28] => Array ( [id] => 349933730 [first_name] => Viktor [last_name] => Grigorievich [online] => 0 ) 
    [29] => Array ( [id] => 420661927 [first_name] => William [last_name] => Clinton [online] => 0 ) 
    [30] => Array ( [id] => 164133743 [first_name] => Peliculaskid [last_name] => Com [online] => 0 ) 
    [31] => Array ( [id] => 335518207 [first_name] => César [last_name] => Eduardo [online] => 0 ) 
    [32] => Array ( [id] => 205049120 [first_name] => Carlos [last_name] => Salgado [online] => 0 ) 
    ) 
    ) 
    );
```

E usado algunas maneras de recorrer el array como por ejemplo :

```
echo implode(" ",$array[0][1]);

$ids = array_column($array ['items'], 'id');
Echo $ids;

$contenido="";
foreach($array["items"] as $row){ 
    $contenido .= $row["id"].PHP_EOL; 
}


Hecho $contenido;
```

Todas sin resultado .

Comment: Ese array está mal formateado amigo, fijate que los elementos de un arreglo deben estar separados por comas, cosa que no pasa en el arreglo que pones como ejemplo, tambien las keys del array deben estar entrecomilladas, eso tampoco pasa en tu arreglo.

Comment: Este array lo obtengo de un json  $array = json_decode($resjson,true);

Comment: Podrías colocar esa info en tu pregunta y el valor de $resjson así lo podemos replicar al problema?

Comment: Listo pregunta  editada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí les dejo mi propia respuesta simplificado las otras respuestas .

```
$posts = $array['response']['items'];

foreach($posts as $P){

$RN = $P['id'];
echo $RN. '<br>';
}
```

Usando array_column() el ciclo es mas rápido que foreach() ejemplo

```
$id = array_column( $array['response']['items'], 'id');
echo  $id;
```

Otra forma es accediendo al id directamente ejemplo:

```
echo $array['response']['items']['0']['id'];
```

Igual es justo recordar otra manera fácil de lograrlo usando implode();

```
echo implode(" ",$array['response']['items']['0']['id']);
```

Saludes y gracias totales

Comment: echo va en minúsculas

Comment: @anonimo es un error del predicativo del celular

Answer (score 2):

para recorrer array asociativos se recomienda el ciclo for each  por ejemplo si quisieras recorrer el array que describes puedes acceder directamente al indice items,podria ser asi

```
 $items=$array["response"]["items"];
 foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    $fila=$value; // obtiene fila de array actual
    echo $fila["nombre"]."\n"; //accediendo a propiedad

    //si quieres acceder a una propiedad que no esta en todas las filas debes preguntar si existe el indice 

    if(array_key_exists("online_mobile",$fila)){ // propiedad que esta presente solo en algunas filas
     echo $fila["online_mobile"];
    }




 }
```

Comment: Tu código da el siguiente error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$key' (T_VARIABLE) supongo que no recorre el array .

Comment: error de sintaxis revisare

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions ahora lo actualice

Comment: Podrías usar el array que muestro en la pregunta junto a tu código para sacar los id . y veras que no recorre el array por eso de el error

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions  el error es de sintaxis, probaste ahora cuando actualice el codigo.

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions el array que pusite en el codigo es proveniente de un print_r ?

Comment: Si el array es de un print_r();

Comment: Gracias @josemigueljara con algunos detalles que agregar y aunque falto un poco de explicación del código tu respuesta me dio un par de ideas . muchas gracias

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions de nada, soy nuevo en esto de ayudar pero voy aprendiendo poco a poco, suerte en tu  desarrollo

Comment: Igual amigo . espero poder ayudarte en algún momento de futuro ..

Answer (score 2):

Primero considerar que yo no sabía que podías tener nombres de arrays asociativos sin comillas, pero tal parece que eso no es un problema..., salvo que deberás respetar el nombre sin comillas, sino no funciona la referencia.

Lo que hice fue anidar 3 bucles for porque el array es tridimensional.

El siguiente código te permitirá iterar correctamente por ese array:

```
<?php

$resjson = '{"response":{"count":377,"items":[{"id":217775120,"first_name":"Hernán","last_name":"Báez","online":0},{"id":195876267,"first_name":"Padisc","last_name":"Vintage","online":0},{"id":300583272,"first_name":"Emiliano","last_name":"Grecco","online":0},{"id":188512977,"first_name":"Espanol","last_name":"Network","online":0},{"id":286516269,"first_name":"Dani","last_name":"Dan","online":0},{"id":526309153,"first_name":"Leonardo","last_name":"Sánchez","online":0},{"id":264060759,"first_name":"Miguel","last_name":"Zavarof","online":0},{"id":318847339,"first_name":"Canalpelis","last_name":"Online","online":0},{"id":282800022,"first_name":"Josemaria","last_name":"Nieto Tierra","online":0},{"id":173457305,"first_name":"Teodoro","last_name":"Lopez","online":0},{"id":520902659,"first_name":"Blue","last_name":"Love","online":0},{"id":162523459,"first_name":"Marcos","last_name":"Férnandez","online":0},{"id":502843767,"first_name":"Guillermo","last_name":"Calderon","online":0},{"id":494597552,"first_name":"Carina-Eugenia","last_name":"Calonga","online":0},{"id":336520601,"first_name":"Román","last_name":"Ruiz","online":0},{"id":357708754,"first_name":"Ciudad","last_name":"Cultural","online":0},{"id":421137904,"first_name":"Rafa","last_name":"Castro","online":0},{"id":353603786,"first_name":"Ed","last_name":"Vallejo","online":0},{"id":262003746,"first_name":"Alejandro","last_name":"Frutos-Comparetto","online":0},{"id":538493295,"first_name":"Raúl","last_name":"Caraveo Toledo","online":0},{"id":400782191,"first_name":"Xwall","last_name":"Ricardi","online":0},{"id":210222972,"first_name":"Gen","last_name":"Iero","online":0},{"id":325434135,"first_name":"Iván","last_name":"Villar","online":0},{"id":311177154,"first_name":"Francisco-Javier","last_name":"Calzada-Lopez","online":0},{"id":169051516,"first_name":"Pepe","last_name":"Tansolo","online":0},{"id":312662742,"first_name":"Anabel","last_name":"Rodriguez","online":0},{"id":331548225,"first_name":"Jose","last_name":"Gomez","online":0},{"id":349933730,"first_name":"Viktor","last_name":"Grigorievich","online":0},{"id":288056567,"first_name":"Franco","last_name":"Liotta","online":0},{"id":420661927,"first_name":"William","last_name":"Clinton","online":0},{"id":164133743,"first_name":"Peliculaskid","last_name":"Com","online":0},{"id":335518207,"first_name":"César","last_name":"Eduardo","online":0},{"id":205049120,"first_name":"Carlos","last_name":"Salgado","online":0},{"id":432792923,"first_name":"Emilio","last_name":"Gomez-Vera","online":0},{"id":199299884,"first_name":"Aleister","last_name":"Crowley","online":0},{"id":143625934,"first_name":"Enrique","last_name":"Amaya","online":0},{"id":365862403,"first_name":"Nestor","last_name":"Castro","online":0},{"id":220163416,"first_name":"Mia","last_name":"Solorzano","online":0},{"id":285677321,"first_name":"Luna","last_name":"Gelida","online":0},{"id":336166138,"first_name":"Ana","last_name":"Rang","online":0},{"id":366348914,"first_name":"Agenda","last_name":"Sociocultural","online":0},{"id":144629714,"first_name":"Tonalli","last_name":"Arteaga","online":0},{"id":526854716,"first_name":"Miguel","last_name":"Martínez","online":0},{"id":274247897,"first_name":"Jorge","last_name":"Carmona","online":0},{"id":494721586,"first_name":"Johnbritto","last_name":"Britto","online":0},{"id":524461342,"first_name":"Richard","last_name":"Mazzoccone","online":0},{"id":465222660,"first_name":"Mauro","last_name":"Buitrago","online":0},{"id":231767284,"first_name":"Silvia","last_name":"Caadas","online":0},{"id":215306065,"first_name":"Darío","last_name":"Billani","online":0},{"id":172382488,"first_name":"Chimo","last_name":"Dimension","online":0},{"id":253572519,"first_name":"Carmen","last_name":"Oliveros","online":0},{"id":57067305,"first_name":"David","last_name":"Bofill","online":0},{"id":529416825,"first_name":"Sibila","last_name":"Crombas","online":0},{"id":273480697,"first_name":"Sandra","last_name":"Martinez Mancebo","online":0},{"id":184056171,"first_name":"Estefania","last_name":"Farias","online":0}]}}';

$array = json_decode($resjson,true); 




foreach ($array as $items => $items_value) {
    foreach ($items_value as $item => $item_value) {
        if($item == "count"){
            echo "<h1>TOTAL: " . $item_value . "</h1><br />";
        }

        foreach ($item_value as $persona => $datos) {
            echo "<h3>ID PERSONA => " . $datos[id];
            echo "---" . $datos[first_name ] . " " . $datos[last_name ] . "</h3><br />";
            // etc etc etc
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva bro!

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu respuesta la pondre en práctica